# JavaScript, Funciones: Parámetros por defecto, ¿este es un correcto ejemplo?

Tags: javascript, funciones, parámetros

No tengo muchos conocimientos en JavaScript, estaba leyendo en un libro sobre Funciones y parámetros por defecto y muestra este ejemplo:

```
function saludar( tipo, nombre ) {
  var tipo = tipo || "hola";
  var nombre = nombre || "Stiven";

  return(tipo + ", " + nombre);
}
```

Pero en el visual studio code, me muestra un error diciendo que tipo y nombre ya se encuentran definidas. por lo que me surge la siguiente pregunta, ¿dentro de la función se pueden crear variables con el mismo nombre que sus parámetros?, si es así, ¿está es la forma correcta de hacerlo?.

muchas gracias, si depronto disponen de un ejemplo mejor para este tema se los agradecería :D

Answer (score 1):

Si, el problema es que tienes una variable que recibes por parámetro que se llama `tipo`,
y estás declarando una nueva variable con el mismo nombre usando la palabra reservada `var`.

Lo correcto seria redeclarar la variable que recibes por parámetro.

```
function saludar( tipo, nombre ) {
  tipo = tipo || "hola";
  nombre = nombre || "Stiven";

  return(tipo + ", " + nombre);
}
```

si ves, solo quité la palabra reservada `var`.

Si lo que quieres es mantener el valor de la variable que recibes por parámetro, debes declararlo con un nuevo nombre, ya que no puedes tener 2 variables con el mismo nombre en un mismo contexto.

cuando me hablo del contexto, me refiero como al entorno donde te encuentras.
algo que si puedes hacer es esto:

```
var miVar = 'Ejemplo'

function ejemplo(){
  var miVar = 'Ejemplo 2'
  return miVar
}

console.log( miVar )
console.log( ejemplo() )
```

imagina que tienes una cuarto y cada cuarto solo permite 1 televisor, pero si el cuarto, tiene un cuarto adentro, este cuarto también puede tener su propio televisor y así sucesivamente.